# sql assigned to a variable couldn't be printed/queried when executing a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @DROP_SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @create_Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @tablename2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @insert_sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @db_schema NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @db_schema='GGW'
SET @tablename2='VIEW_LOG'
DECLARE @count INT
SET @count=1

DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME
DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME
SET @StartTime =GETDATE()
SET @EndTime=GETDATE()

DECLARE @schema_nm NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @schema_nm='GW'

DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @tablename='x'


SET @drop_sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [GW].['+@tablename2+']'
PRINT @drop_sql
EXEC(@drop_sql)


SET @create_Sql = 'CREATE TABLE [GGW].[VIEW_LOG] (
        schema_name NVARCHAR(MAX),
        view_name NVARCHAR(max)
        ,row_count INT
        ,error_msg NVARCHAR(max)
        ,query_start_time DATETIME
        ,query_end_time DATETIME
        ,execution_time_in_ms NVARCHAR(max)
        );'
PRINT @create_Sql
EXEC(@create_Sql)



SET @insert_sql='INSERT INTO ['+@db_schema+'].['+@tablename2+'] SELECT '+ @schema_nm+','+@tablename+','+CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@count)+','+NULL+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @StartTime)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @EndTime)+','+CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime)) 
PRINT(@insert_sql)
EXEC(@insert_sql)
```

I have created a table and trying to insert some records in to the table. the insert statement is assigned to a variable which is @insert_sql. i am trying to execute the sql that i have created and assigned to  variable but it couldn't be printed or executed. am i missing something here?

Comment: *"but it couldn't be printed or executed"* Why couldn't it?

Comment: It's generally advised to not use syntax such as `EXEC (@SQL);`. Such statements cannot be parametrised, which promote bad habits that result in security flaws like SQL injection. If you need to run a statement that is within a variable or literal string then use [`sys.sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql). Then you can easily parametrise the statement if you need to.

Comment: When I run the SQL in a sandbox, I get that the value of `@insert_sql` is `NULL` prior to it being `PRINT`ed `EXEC`uted, hence why nothing is run. Considering that neither `@db_schema` and `@tablename2` (which are being insecurely by the way, `'[' + @SomeVariable + ']'` is **not** injection safe; use `QUOTENAME`) aren't `NULL` that means that if you properly parametrised your statement, the query would work.

Comment: You also have inconsistent schemas in the above. You hard code it to `GW` and `GGW` in a couple of places, and then inject it in others.

Comment: In your `INSERT` line you're doing `+','+NULL+','` which is making the string NULL.

Comment: Also, while we're talking bout all the problems with the injection, you give someone malicious **2GB** of characters to play with. The correct data type for object names is `sysname`; a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`.

Comment: You have `SET @insert_sql='INSERT INTO ['+@variables...` Have you tried printing each of the variables, since any of those being NULL will render the whole thing NULL. Also, please read [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's so much wrong with the above... The comments under the question touch why the above fails, you concatenate `NULL` to your string which results in `NULL`, and I highlight some more below and in the comments of the SQL. Of course, you shouldn't be using that concatenation at all and should be **parametrising** your *parameters*.

There's a lot of inconsistencies in the SQL too; varying references to schema names, some hard coded others not. I've replaced any schema references with `dbo` to avoid incorrect assumptions.

I also inject your object names, where there is dynamic SQL, safely with `QUOTENAME`. `'[' + @SomeVariable + ']'` is **NOT** injection safe; especially when you give someone 2GB/~1 billion characters to "play" with. A right bracket (`]`) can just as easily be escaped as a single quote (`'`), and with 2GB of data, someone malicious can do *literally* what ever they want; your code is a security vulnerability waited to be exploited.

I make some assumptions on data types, and I've not tested this, but it should, at least, get you much closer to the desired behaviour.

```sql
DECLARE @DROP_SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @create_Sql nvarchar(MAX),
        @tablename2 sysname,
        @insert_sql nvarchar(MAX),
        @db_schema sysname;
SET @db_schema = N'dbo';
SET @tablename2 = N'VIEW_LOG';
DECLARE @count int;
SET @count = 1;

DECLARE @StartTime datetime,
        @EndTime datetime;
SET @StartTime = GETDATE();
SET @EndTime = GETDATE();

DECLARE @schema_nm sysname;
SET @schema_nm = 'dbo';

DECLARE @tablename sysname;
SET @tablename = 'x';


SET @DROP_SQL = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + QUOTENAME(@db_schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename2) + N';';
--PRINT @drop_sql
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

--This query wasn't dynamic, so there's no point making it dynamic.
--Though the data types are all wrong here, see the comments below, but I create it with more correct data types
/*
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VIEW_LOG] (
        schema_name NVARCHAR(MAX), --Should this really be sysname?
        view_name NVARCHAR(max), --Should this really be sysname?
        row_count INT,
        error_msg NVARCHAR(max), --Is your error really likely to be 4,000 characters or more? 
        query_start_time DATETIME,
        query_end_time DATETIME,
        execution_time_in_ms NVARCHAR(max)); --If it's time in ms, why is this an nvarchar(MAX)? Stop (ab)using nvarchar(MAX)
*/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VIEW_LOG] (schema_name sysname,
                               view_name sysname,
                               row_count int,
                               error_msg nvarchar(4000),
                               query_start_time datetime,
                               query_end_time datetime,
                               execution_time_in_ms int);
--PRINT @db_schema
--PRINT @tablename2
DECLARE @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10); --Let's add some whitespace and line breaks to this query

SET @insert_sql = N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@db_schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename2) + N' (schema_name, view_name, row_count, error_msg, query_start_time, query_end_time, execution_time_in_ms)' + @CRLF + N'VALUES(@schema_nm,@tablename,@count,NULL,@StartTime,@EndTime,DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,@EndTime));';
--PRINT(@insert_sql)
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL,
                       N'@schema_nm sysname,@tablename sysname,@count int,@StartTime datetime,@EndTime datetime',
                       @schema_nm,
                       @tablename,
                       @count,
                       @StartTime,
                       @EndTime;
```

Comment: I am not that good at SQL procedures which is why i have made a lot of mistakes. Thanks a ton for taking time to look at it and correcting the mistakes that i have done.